# Output line counts for files with 1 number filename difference

Tags: linux, bash, date

We have a requirement to report on the number of lines written to a 7 day cycle of log files.  The log files are called - `[filename].log.1.gz` for today, `[filename].log.2.gz` for yesterday up to `[filename].log.7.gz` for the 7th day

I was hoping to create a script that would output the numbers at once, instead of running the `zcat [filename].log.1.gz | wc -l` command against each line.  I was also hoping to have a meaningful message against each outputted value

I can write a bash script that will do each line as the name of the files are the same, but I was hoping for something a bit more elegant

Instead of this

```
zcat position.log.3.gz | wc -l
zcat position.log.4.gz | wc -l
zcat position.log.5.gz | wc -l
zcat position.log.6.gz | wc -l
zcat position.log.7.gz | wc -l
```

I was hoping for something more like this

```
for i in {1..7}
c=$(zcat position.log.$i.gz | wc -l)
message=$"The count for "
date1=$(date --date='$i days ago')
result=$"$message$date1$c"
echo $result
done
```

However, I can't get this to run.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add `; do` after `for i in {1..7}`, change this `(date --date='$i days ago')` to this `(date --date="$i days ago")`

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You script with small fixes:

```
# for loop starts with a 'do'
for i in {1..7}; do
   # indentation makes everything redable
   # always quote your variables
   c=$(zcat "position.log.$i.gz" | wc -l)
   # The "" is just a string, no '$' sign before it
   message="The count for "
   # The '$i' is literally `$i`, if you want to _expand_ a variable, you have to use "$i"
   date1=$(date --date="$i days ago")
   # same as above, drop the $
   result="$message$date1$c"
   # always quote your variables
   echo "$result"
done
```

Or maybe a tiny little bit shorter:

```
for i in {1..7}; do
   echo "The count for $(date --date="$i days ago") is $(zcat "position.log.$i.gz" | wc -l)"
done
```

Comment: Thanks Kamil.  The shorter version is what I was looking for.  As you can tell, I am new to Linux, so thanks for taking the time to answer what is probably a very simple question